# Sort CSV file based on first column

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, unix, csv

Is there a way to sort a csv file based on the 1st column using some shell command?

I have this huge file with more than 150k lines hence I can do it in excel:( is there an alternate way ?

Comment: Have you tried the `sort` command ?? see `man sort` for details

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`sort -k1 -n -t, filename` should do the trick.

`-k1` sorts by column 1.

`-n` sorts numerically instead of lexicographically (so "11" will not come before "2,3...").

`-t,` sets the delimiter (what separates values in your file) to `,` since your file is comma-separated.

Comment: Probably convenient to also set the field separator `-t` to `,` ? ;-)

Comment: NOTE: This approach will **fail** on valid CSV files where entries contain newlines, so one CSV entry spans multiple lines in the file.

Comment: To sort by only one column, you should use `-k1,1` (see https://superuser.com/questions/33362/how-to-unix-sort-by-one-column-only)

Comment: Comment to others who'd like to use this: If your separator is a *semicolon* `;` instead of a comma, then you might want to escape it: `-t\;`

Comment: This did not work for me, using -k1,1 did though.Only -k1 produced something like: 1,10551  1,19163  18,5718   2,16561

Comment: @SybillePeters same, `--debug` gave me this hint: `sort: field separator ‘,’ is treated as a group separator in numbers`

Answer (score 13):

I don't know why above solution was not working in my case.

```
15,5
17,2
18,6
19,4
8,25
8,90
9,47
9,49
10,67
10,90
13,96
159,9
```

however this command solved my problem.

```
sort -t"," -k1n,1 fileName
```

Comment: NOTE: This approach will **fail** on valid CSV files where entries contain newlines, so one CSV entry spans multiple lines in the file.

Comment: This answer worked for me, whereas the accepted answer failed.

Comment: @k314159 (and at OP): `--debug` gave me the hint: `sort: field separator ‘,’ is treated as a group separator in numbers`

Answer (score 12):

#### Using `csvsort`.

1. Install `csvkit` if not already installed.

   ```
   brew install csvkit
   ```
2. Sort CSV by first column.

   ```
   csvsort -c 1 original.csv > sorted.csv
   ```

Comment: @fiddle The existing solutions sorted my column of numbers incorrectly, however, `csvsort` worked perfectly with the defaults. That's a useful thing to me and it might be to others. Only time will tell.

Comment: This is the only one of the answers that handles valid entries that span multiple lines.

Comment: This works well when you have string values surrounded by double quotes containing commas (",")